# How to dynamically update data in link on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have say 3 different sets of filters like below:

```
<div class="filter1">
<ul>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param1="1">Some link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param2="2">Some link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param3="3">Some link3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to dynamically append/update param of the link by window.location.href onclick

Something like this:

```
$('.filter1 li a').on('click',function(){window.location.href += $(this).data('data-param1');})
```

So the link will be domain.com/site/filter?param1=1

then after clicking another filter link it will be updated to domain.com/site/filter?param1=1&?param2=2

But,
if will be clicked the link that have been already clicked, it should not append but update param

How can I manage that by js/jQuery? Or maybe there are some another method of implementing that task?

Hope it make sense!

Many thanks in advance!

Update:
to **badAdviceGuy:**
No need of location.hash, link must navigate page to new address with some new params. But the issue is to add and, if param already in the link, to update current param.

Comment: why not write it in `href`,like `<a href="?parem1=1">some link1</a>`

Comment: Mm, how does it suppose to help?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly this may help.

In for modifying the `window.location` without navigating away from the current page, i'm fond of using `window.location.hash`. I'd also get all of your html data attributes the same too.

HTML:

```
<div class="filter1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="filter1">Some link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="filter2">Some link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="filter3">Some link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.filter1 li a').on('click',function(){window.location.hash = $(this).data('data-param');})
```

Comment: No need of location.hash, link must navigate page to new address with some new params. But the issue is to add and, if param already in the link, to update current param.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filter1 ul li a').on('click',function(e)
{
window.location.href = "domain.com/site/filter?param" + $(this).data('param') + "=" + $(this).data('param');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="filter1">
<ul>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="1">Some link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="2">Some link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascrript:void(0)" data-param="3">Some link3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```